# how to generate a series representing the binary expansion of 'e'

Tags: algorithm, haskell, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to find the first 100,000 binary digits in the expansion of 'e'. Is there an algorithm to generate the binary digits of 'e' as a infinite list?

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144154/code-to-generate-e-one-digit-at-a-time

Comment: See e.g. "unbounded spigot algorithms" for example, Pi, http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf

Comment: Why don't you just take the digits from somewhere else (e.g. here: http://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/e.1mil ) and convert it to a binary representation at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an unbounded spigot for `e` in Haskell:

```
main = print $ stream (1,0,1) [(n, a*d, d) | (n,d,a) <- map f [1..]]
    where
        f k = (1, k, 1)

stream z (x:xs)
    | lbound == approx z 2 = lbound : stream (mul (10, -10*lbound, 1) z) (x:xs)
    | otherwise            =          stream (mul z x) xs
  where
    lbound = approx z 1

approx (a,b,c) n = (a*n + b) `div` c

mul (a,b,c) (d,e,f) = (a*d, a*e + b*f, c*f)
```

Based on the Programming Praxis [unbounded spigot for e and pi](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/06/19/digits-of-e/), which in turn is derived from [Gibbon's first unbounded spigot for pi.](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf)

```
$ runhaskell A.hs
[2,7,1,8,2,8,1,8,2,8,4,5,9,0,4,5,2,3,5,3,6, ^C
```

I'd recommend Gibbon's paper if you're interested in these fun algorithms.

Comment: If I need to change it to output binary, do I just replace the 10 with 2?

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in using [CReal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/numbers/3000.1.0.3/doc/html/Data-Number-CReal.html) for this. For 100,000 binary digits, 30,200 decimal digits is enough:

```
Prelude> 100000 * logBase 10 2
30102.999566398114
Prelude> :m + Data.Number.CReal
Prelude> :set +s
Prelude Data.Number.CReal> last $ showCReal 1000 (exp 1)
'4'
(0.34 secs, 34061824 bytes)
Prelude Data.Number.CReal> last $ showCReal 2000 (exp 1)
'4'
(1.25 secs, 104478784 bytes)
Prelude Data.Number.CReal> last $ showCReal 4000 (exp 1)
'7'
(5.96 secs, 355775928 bytes)
Prelude Data.Number.CReal> last $ showCReal 8000 (exp 1)
'2'
(20.89 secs, 1298942504 bytes)
```

This pattern looks about quadratic to me, so computing the first 30,200 digits of `exp 1` looks like it might reasonably finish in about five or six minutes here on my machine. A patch to output in binary directly (and therefore avoid converting to decimal and back) would likely be accepted.

edit: Projection satisfied, just under six minutes of compute time!

```
Prelude Data.Number.CReal> showCReal 30200 (exp 1)
"2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334...middle snipped due to StackOverflow message limit...39106913376148418348845963656215266103322394174671"
(349.44 secs, 17096829912 bytes)
```